# Angular 2 data binding first time issues

Tags: angular, angular2-template

My workflow is after login, it navigates to profiles page where it calls for profiles API and just render it to HTML. The problem is I get result from API in a very short span but HTML rendering takes a long time to render approx 10-15 secs. And when I do a refresh on profiles page, it renders HTML instantly.
What may I be doing wrong here.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>{{profiles.name}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>{{profiles.email}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.profilesService.getProfiles()
    .subscribe(res => {
        // console.log(res);
        if(!res.err){
            this.profiles = res.data[0];
            // console.log(this.profiles);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell. What does profiling in the browsers devtools tell you what the browser is waiting for?

Comment: It returns data almost instantly, I can see data in console

Comment: Check the `Timeline` tab in the browsers devtools.

Comment: It's also normal


Total: 17.10 s
4.3 msLoading
233.7 msScripting
59.9 msRendering
31.2 msPainting
173.5 msOther
16593.1 msIdle

Comment: I never said anything like that. It's not normal. Angular2 is super fast but I don't have any information here about why it might be slow for you. I just make suggestions where you can look for possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

```
JS:

//define profile variable as Observable
profiles: Observable<any>

ngOnInit() {
    this.profiles = this.profilesService.getProfiles()
    .map(res => {
      //take only .data[0]
        return res.data[0]
    });
}

HTML
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>{{(profiles | async)?.name}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>{{(profiles | async)?.email}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```